# Excel Nested IF statements returning False

Tags: excel

I am constructing a nested IF statement, and I believe I am missing an ELSE but I cannot figure out where. I have the following statement:

```
=

IF(AND(B2="4",E2="R37",X2="Y"), "Non-Competing",

IF(AND(B2="4",E2="R37",X2="N"), "Competing",

IF(AND(B2="4",E2<>"R37",RIGHT(Z2,2)="00"), "Non-Competing",

IF(AND(B2="4",E2<>"R37",RIGHT(Z2,2)<>"00"), "Competing",

IF(B2<>"4","-")))))
```

I thought the last bit would cover the rest, but I am receiving a FALSE when I was hoping to get a result. For example, when B2=4, E2=R37, and X2=Y, I am expecting "Non-Competing" but am receiving FALSE. I also tried a combination with OR:

```
IF(OR(AND(B41="4",E41="R37",X41="Y"), 

AND(B41="4",E41<>"R37",RIGHT(Z41,2)="00")), "Non-Competing",

IF(OR(AND(B41="4",E41="R37",X41="N"), AND(B41="4",E41<>"R37",RIGHT(Z41,2)

<>"00")), "Competing",

IF(B41<>"4","-")))
```

...which gives me the same result.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you pull the single IF line out and reference the same data does it work?

Answer (score 0):

The missing else is in `IF(B2<>"4","-")`.  You need `IF(B2<>"4","-",<whatever last-ditch-answer>)` If you are reaching `False`, then `B2` is 4, but none of the other full conditions were met.

Without seeing your data, I can't know for sure, but I'm guessing that you may have intended that entire statement to behave as an else.  If that is case, I would replace `IF(B2<>"4","-")` directly with `"-"`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! You are correct in that I wanted the whole statement to behave as the Else. I replaced it with "-" but still received "-" when I shouldn't have. I'm thinking there is a hole with one (or more) of IF statements but I just can't seem to locate it.

Comment: I figured it out! I was putting apostrophes around the 4 so it wasn't being read as a numerical value. Thank you so much for the help with the Else statement! :)